# Blank Project. Premature end of file

Tags: eclipse

I am having a problem. When I opened my Eclipse, the project I'm doing is having an error which is premature end of file. Everytime I clicked my Java, XML and AndroidManifest, I got this error "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException". It is not opening. I tried those answers here but nothing works. Hope you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project, then copying each of the files one by one (or at least in small groups) back into the new one.  If everything works, you're set.  Otherwise, you can at least isolate the problem.  A NPE from the project could be just about anything, so this will likely be your best bet.